# Expose Generated files to realm in another module

Tags: java, android, realm, code-generation

I implemented a lib that handles network and database (realm) access. Currently my lib is in another module than my sample app. Every model in the app needs 2 versions, a realm object and a regular POJO. I wrote an annotation processor to generate the equivalent realm class file from my annotated POJO. The problem is that my generated class is not part of the schema.

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: class com.zeyad.usecases.app.presentation.models.AutoMap_UserModel is not part of the schema for this Realm.
```

I assume because its in the generated files directory. Is there way to expose the generated files to the schema ? thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered reading the [***docs***](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sharing-schemas)?

Comment: yes, i do not think it works with generated files. Because i have this configuration and it works fine with normal files. Also when i take out the generated file from the generated directory and put it with the rest of the code it works fine

Comment: Even if you generate a RealmModule which contains the classes for the generated classes, it doesn't work?

Comment: If you mean that i generate classes that implement RealmModule with the RealmClass annotation. then yes it still doesnt work.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a module class in your library module and add that module in configuration of your Realm in application onCreate(), like this

```
import io.realm.annotations.RealmModule;

@RealmModule(library = true, allClasses = true)
public class MessengerModule {
}
```

this in your library

```
Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration configuration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .modules(Realm.getDefaultModule(), new MessengerModule())
        .build();
Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(configuration);
```

and this is your application onCreate

Comment: What is your exception message?

Comment: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: class com.zeyad.usecases.app.presentation.models.AutoMap_UserModel is not part of the schema for this Realm.